# socat route tcp6 traffic to tcp4

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, socat

I'm using `socat` to route incoming tcp6 to tcp4.  The destination (tcp4) is a pod/container with the pod service external-ip.  Within the container I use `ncat` to listen for the port 5555.

```
# socat TCP6-LISTEN:5555,reuseaddr,fork,bind=[fe80::250:56ff:fe91:bd5c%ens192] TCP4:10.40.5.125:5555 (Update)
```

socat return Connection refused (Update)

```
2018/07/27 01:15:41 socat[26914] E connect(5, AF=2 10.40.5.125:5555, 16): Connection refused
```

I'm getting no acknowledgment from within the container (`# ncat -4 -vv --exec cat -l -p 5555`)

I try to use `-vv` & `-lf` in the `socat` command to get more information about the tcp6 traffic but no significant log was written to the log file.

Before attempting tcp6 format I was able to route tcp4 traffic to tcp4 same destination listed above using `socat`.  The command is below,

```
# socat TCP-LISTEN:5555,fork TCP:10.101.74.206:5555
```

Can someone please point what I am missing for tcp6?

OS: CentOS 7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $ ncat -4 -vv --exec cat -l -p 5555
> ```

`nmap`'s `ncat` requires a full path for its `--exec` parameter. Use `/bin/cat` instead of `cat`.

> I try to use -vv & -lf in the socat command to get more information about the tcp6 traffic but no significant log was written to the log file.

To get verbose `socat` output, specify the `-d` switch a few times.

Other than the above issues, I managed to successfully reproduce your setup, and it seems to work as you've intended. Check the debug output to narrow down your problem.

Comment: Thank you for responding Vladimir.  I think my issue is the ipv6 I'm hitting is [fe80:::] and not [201:::].  Not sure I understand the difference one is for gateway and the 201:: is the actual IPV6 ip address?

Comment: Vladimir, Did you use the ipv6 fe80:::: (unicast)? Does make any different if the IPV6 address is unicast, multicast, anycast?

Comment: I used `::1` to connect to `socat` to test this setup.

Comment: @bamb00 when using a *link layer* ipv6 address, you must include the interface name in the address to reference it unambiguously. So if an external socat was doing the IPv6 connection, that would be for eg `socat 'tcp6:[fe80::1234:5678%eth0]:5555' -`

Comment: @A.B I include the interface name but return "Name or service not known" the interface ens224 is running in the vm.
        # socat -ddd TCP6:[2001:10:40:1:cf39:d82e:c546:1aca%ens224]:5555 TCP4:10.40.5.125:5555

Comment: your example is not a *link layer* ipv6 address, but a global address, thus doesn't require an interface name at all. link layer usually start with fe80. My comment was made because you wrote you had trouble with a fe80: ... address. Beside, the *local* interface name has to be chosen and used (here with the destination, other usages could be the source). It's to be considered like a route sort-of, because link layers are not unique, there are only unique per interface. How would a remote interface name be known?

Comment: @A.B I apologize for the mix-up.  This is what I end up using "socat TCP6-LISTEN:5555,reuseaddr,fork,bind=[fe80::250:56ff:fe91:bd5c%ens192] TCP4:10.40.5.125:5555".  I think is the same from your suggestion.  Now, I can see from ncat it is connected to ipv6 address,
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT SUCCESS for EID 8 [fe80::250:56ff:fe91:bd5c:5555]
Ncat: Connected to fe80::250:56ff:fe91:bd5c:5555.

But it seems it is not routing to tcp4 as socat return "socat[7245] E connect(5, AF=2 10.40.5.125:5555, 16): Connection refused".

Comment: [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Comment: I was using an incorrect port.  I use tcpdump to track the packet route to the containers.  Thank you y'all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why `socat` refuses to connect IPv4 host. Just to save your time my suggestion for you is to use `stone` repeater instead of `socat`. Install it (I hope this package has been included in CentOS):

```
yum install stone
```

Execute it with debug level 5 (verbose mode):

```
stone -ddddd 110.101.74.206:5555 5555/v6
```

Test your connection using `telnet` and if everything works well, remove `-ddddd` option and run the `stone` in the way you want in production mode. For example, run `stone` as daemon with 20 child processes spawned:

```
stone -D -f 20 110.101.74.206:5555 5555/v6
```

Check the running `stone` processes afterwards:

```
ps aux | grep stone
```

**Additional information:**

- [stone version 2.3e](http://www.gcd.org/sengoku/stone/)
- [FreeBSD Manual Pages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stone)
- [Stone: An awesome packet repeater tool that will save your day](http://codelectron.com/stone-an-awesome-packet-repeater-tool-that-will-save-your-day/)

Comment: Thank You for responding.  I will definitely check out stone.  Do you know if stone is use in a production env?

Comment: @bamb00 Yes, you can and you'll see that `stone` is more stable than `socat`. Consider only  `-D` option (run as daemon), `-f` option for number of child processe to spawn, and of course options: `-u`, `-X`, `-T`, `-A` - read FreeBSD man (link is in my answer above).

Comment: Does stone listen for tcp traffic whether is from tcp4 or tcp6 without having to specify v4 or v6 meaning does not care if is ipv4 or ipv6?

Comment: @bamb00 You have run two `stone`s separately and simultaneously if you want to listen both ipv4 and ipv6. For ipv6 run it with `5555/v6` and for ipv4 - `5555`. In the example in answer with `/v6` option it listens `110.101.74.206:5555 <- :::5555/v6`. Without `/v6` the routing is `110.101.74.206:5555 <- 0.0.0.0:5555`

Comment: There are no package for CentOS 7.

Comment: @bamb00 Hmm... Ubuntu universe repo includes `stone` package. Install it from source: https://gist.github.com/int128/fbdccb7bee7775f5b0e0

Comment: Do you know if stone support preserve the source IP once the packet is forward to it destination via K8s pod/container?

Comment: Seems to get alot of compiling error "# make linux"

     # stone.c: In function ‘strnUser’:
stone.c:4509:32: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
      socklen_t optlen = sizeof(*cred);
                                ^
    # stone.c:4524:46: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
      snprintf(str, STRMAX, "%d", (cred ? cred->gid : -1));
                                              ^

Comment: @bamb00 Open `Makefile` in text editor, find lines `linux: $(MAKE)...`  and after `-DUSE_EPOLL` add the new option `-D_GNU_SOURCE`. Save changes. Execute `make linux` again and check if compiled `stone` binary has appeared afterwards.

Comment: When stone capture the incoming traffic info? Is there anyway I can pass those info along with the packet to the destination (pod/container)? I can see the packet info but I want to know who sent the packet (source IP).  The info is capture by stone "accepted TCP 5 from fe80::250:56ff:fe91:56bd%ens192:58220/v6 mode=0".